# Munin UNKNOWN spamming

Tags: monitoring, munin

By adding `unknown_limit 50` to `munin.conf` I've been able to drastically decrease the number of emails I receive from hosts that generate an otherwise acceptable level of `UNKNOWN` values. The problem is that I still get all the `OK` notifications, presumably from those services "recovering." Is there any way to minimize those as well? I've been thoroughly disappointed with Munin's documentation on this and practically any other issue that's come up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We [pipe alerts to an external script](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToContact#Alertstoorthroughexternalscripts) (in python, but can be any executable) and ignore both unknowns and oks:

```
for alert in options.crits + options.warns:
    send_me = True
    ...
```

Once you have the alerts under control, it can actually be quite helpful during a firefight to get periodic status updates.

Comment: Do you use a library for parsing the input? How are you doing it?

Comment: It's an old script, and uses optparse, which has been deprecated in favor of [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html)